# Android unit test to test if setContentView() is called in onCreate()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view, android-testing

Have been searching around for a while but cannot find an answer. Let's say I have this activity with onCreate method like this:

```
private ListView mListView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
}
```

And I have a test class that extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2. How do I test if setContentView is called and set to the right resource once I call onCreate(null) on the activity in test?

```
private someActivity mActivity;
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
  super.setUp();
  mActivity = getActivity();
}

public void testOnCreate() {
  assertNull(mActivity.findViewById(R.id.list_view));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should return the View set using `setContentView()`:

```
View getContentView() {
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.getChildAt(0);
}
```

**Edit:**

Alternately, if the top-level view in the layout has its ID set, you can check if `findViewById(rootId)` returns non-null in your test code.

Comment: I was trying your alternative solution just now. Somehow the assertNull failed before I called onCreate

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar about how Android test framework works. Are you sure that the Activity's `onCreate()` is called before the `assertNull()`?

Comment: onCreate() is not called before that, that's why assertNull should pass right?

Answer (score 1):

We follow a slightly different approach, we used to add an id to the root element of the layout and assert in robolectric unit test as below

For example, consider the below layout xml (Note the id **android:id="@+id/test_layout_root"** ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/test_layout_root"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         ...
         ...
</TableLayout>
```

robolectric unit test code :

```
assertEquals(R.id.test_layout_root, shadowOf(testActivity).getContentView().getId());
```

You can get more details at my blog 
http://ckarthik17-tech.blogspot.in/2013/04/robolectric-testing-setcontentview.html